# sql server seems hung when updating a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a task which I run from the MS SQL Server Management Studio. I would expect it to finish in an hour and it has finished before in such time frame. The input data has not changed dramatically and so I would expect a similar time to execute. But now it seems that sql server stuck. The task has been running over night, in total like 20hrs.

When I open the task manager on the server I see that one core is running at 100% by the sqlservr.exe. The machine has 8 cores. As usual this process has taken over all of the memory ( 30GB ). The SQL Server version is 10.50.1600.1

I'm the only user on the server.

According to dm_exec_requests the session id is 55. And I can pull the correct query text via dm_exec_sql_text. I checked the dm_os_waiting_tasks and the session_id is not part of results.

Here are some more details on the task:

```
status: running
command: UPDATE
start_time: 2013-07-11 14:49:39.533
last_wait_type: SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
open_transaction_count: 2
open_resultset_count: 1
cpu_time: 69315970
total_elapsed_time: 69594247
reads: 5139
writes: 1181434
text_size: -1
```

I did run the process monitor also overnight and there is not much file access to the databases in question.

Can someone tell me what more I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I would start a trace in Management Studio. Ten minutes should be time enough to give you some information on what is happening.

Comment: I have run a trace ( for like 10min ) with all events and only once the session_id 55 showed up which only seem to set some variables like: set quoted_identifier on, etc.